# Animate UINavigationBar from the right

Tags: iphone, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

On my rootViewController in a UINavigationController I have set the UINavigationBar hidden. When I push a new view controller from the right I want the navigation bar to be also "pushed" (animated, whatever) from right. Like in the Email app when you search for an Email, hide the navigation bar, select an email, and the pushed view controller has the Navigation Bar already on top of it, when it is animated from the right, so they are animated together.

Comment: How did you hide the navigation bar in `rootViewController?` You can use the same code to show it, e.g. in `-viewWillAppear` of the pushed-viewController add this method: `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];`

Comment: @Canopus this will not show navigation bar pushed from left or right it shows only from top to down animation read the question carefully

Comment: @Canopus this will not show the navigation bar pushed from the right.